# Problems scalling an image using CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage

Tags: scaling

I'm trying to scale an image using CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage and I'm running into some errors I can't understand.

heres my code

```
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image)
    let cgImage = convertCIImageToCGImage(ciImage)
    let width = 50
    let height = (width / CGImageGetWidth(cgImage)) * CGImageGetHeight(cgImage)
    let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage)
    let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage)
    let colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage)
    let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(cgImage)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)


    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))), cgImage)


    scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!)!
```

and im getting the error

```
<Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Any idea why im getting this error?

Comment: did you find the solution?